# Warning: function 'F' is not needed and will not be emitted

Tags: c++, clang

Here is a little program ([live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e7K1YhTcK)):

```
static void UnusedDeclaration();
static void UnusedDefinition() {}
static void Declaration();

decltype(Declaration())*  global;
```

Ideally I would expect the following warnings, if I compile it with clang, `-Wunused`:

1. `UnusedDeclaration()`: It is an unused function declaration with internal linkage. So I should get a warning.
2. `UnusedDefinition()`: It is an unused function definition with internal linkage. So I should get a warning.
3. `Declaration()`: This declaration is used. So I should **not** get a warning.

Actually all three cases get a warning:

```
warning: unused function 'UnusedDeclaration'
warning: unused function 'UnusedDefinition'
warning: function 'Declaration' is not needed and will not be emitted
```

I have a problem with case 3. I think, the compiler should not warn me about anything, but it does.

- Why do I get a warning for case 3?

  - `function 'Declaration' is not needed` – I honestly need that declaration. I use it in an unevaluated context, the compiler does not need to complain about it.
  - `and will not be emitted` – I am not sure what emitting means. I have written a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58274145/11279879) about it.
- Is there a combination of warning flags to pass to the compiler on the command line, to achieve what I expect (warning for case 1 and 2, no warning for case 3).
- I could turn off warning for case 3 with `-Wunused -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration`, but I don't know if I lose some important information with it. Maybe in some other cases this warning is useful. In what exact situation does this 3rd warning come?

Answer (score 4):

There's no reference to the first function, so it can be basically ignored.

The second function is "called", but as you noted, only in an unevaluated context. That means the call will never be evaluated. The compiler determines the type the function would return if it was called, but that's all. Since it's never actually called, the function itself is never needed or used as a function, so the compiler doesn't generate any code for it.

The messages are different because even though the final effect is the same, each reaches that result slightly differently, and the compiler is trying to give you the information that might be useful.

Comment: "the function itself is never needed or used" -- That is not true. `Needed` is a function declaration, and I need and use it in an unevaluated context to define the global variable `gInt`, which in turn has external linkage, and may be used in another translation unit. So `Needed` it needed. I have to file a bug to clang.

Comment: @Dr.Gut: The *declaration* is used. The function itself is not.

Comment: @Dr.Gut None of what you're saying is evident in the code sample you provided.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I know, but the two things cannot be separated here. One cannot keep the _used declaration_ and remove the _unused function_.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I have rewritten the question. Check it out. Now it is much better. Hopefully this way it will be useful for more people. You might want to rewrite or delete your answer. I was not sure how to handle such a case. Maybe I should have entered a new question, and delete this one. Tell me, if I should do this.