# clang: What does emitting mean?

Tags: c++, clang

The [clang diagnostics reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html) uses the word *emit* three times. The following warnings use this term.

[**Example 1**](https://godbolt.org/z/aa3svfY7P): Compile this with `-Wunneeded-internal-declaration` `-Wunneeded-member-function`:

```
namespace {
    int x;
    int F();

    struct A {
        void M();
    };
}


decltype(x)     global1;
decltype(F())   global2;
decltype(&A::M) global3;
```

You get the following warnings:

```
warning: variable 'x' is not needed and will not be emitted
warning: function 'F' is not needed and will not be emitted
warning: member function 'M' is not needed and will not be emitted
```

[**Example 2**](https://godbolt.org/z/dTnx98cEo): Compile this with `-Wweak-vtables`:

```
class Apple {
    virtual ~Apple() {}
};
```

You get the following warning:

```
warning: 'Apple' has no out-of-line virtual method definitions; its vtable will be emitted in every translation unit
```

**Question**

What does emitting mean?

The most straightforward explanation would be: emitting = generating assembly code. But there are some open questions, if we examine the details.

- In example 1 if we do not use `x`, `F` and `A::M` in unevaluated context, the warnings disappear. So the warning has to do something with unevaluated context.
- In example 1 `F` and `M` are only declarations. Compiler never generates assembly code from a function declaration. So there is no point in giving a warning about it.
- Clang has separate warnings for the case when a variable or function can be proven not to be used. Compile with `-Wunused` ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/eEYqdWWxY)). No assembly code is generated from the variable and the function, and the warnings do not use the term *emit*.
- The warnings that come from `-Wunused` are reported for *definitions* and not *declarations*.

I do not fully understand example 2. I put it here for the sake of completeness. Emitting might mean a slightly different thing here.

Could someone, maybe a clang contributor give some clarification about these questions?

Comment: Might just be an oversight because emitted in this context definitely means "code generated"

Comment: "attempt to compile". Can't be a program as there is no main function. You are also not helping yourself asking the same question multiple times. At least provide a minimum example that has a chance at compiling.

Comment: The [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) uses the term *emission* / *emitted*. It seemingly means *writing to the object file*.

Comment: It means emitting assembly or machine code instructions. Compilers classicaly had a scanner, a parser, a semantic processor, an optimizer, a code generator, and an emitter.

Comment: _Not needed_ sounds like _unused_ to me. Why are these two distinguished as separate warnings?